# How to get keyof include parameter of functions in object?

Tags: typescript

I have data like this

```
const data = {
    inc: (num: number) => num + 1,
    inc2: (num: number, count = 2) => num + count,
}

const convertData = <T, K extends keyof T>(_data:  T): Record<K, number> => _data

const a = convertData(data)
a.inc(2)  // << wrong, Type 'Number' has no compatible call signatures.
```

How to define  the return type of convertData

In this case: `Record<K, number>`

## Updated

If you familar with ramda this example look like this

```
let { compose, mapObjIndexed } = require('ramda')
const inc = (n: number) => n + 1
const inc2 = (n: number) => n + 2
const g = {
    inc,
    inc2,
}
const inc3 = (n: number) => n + 3
const g2 = mapObjIndexed((action: any) => compose(inc3, action))(g)


// But in this case g2 is any, so I have to define type of g2.
// How can I define type of g2 depend on the g?

// => So you can use
console.log('>>', g2.inc(2), g2.inc2(5))
```

Example without ramda

```
let { compose, mapObjIndexed } = require('ramda')
const inc = (n: number) => n + 1
const inc2 = (n: number, count = 2) => n + count
const g = {
    inc,
    inc2,
}
const inc3 = (n: number) => n + 3
const g2: any = Object.keys(g).reduce(
    (previousValue, key) => {
        console.log('props', previousValue, key)
        return {
            ...previousValue,
            [key]: (...arg: any[]) => { return inc3(g[key](...arg)) },
        }
    },
    {})
// const g2 = mapObjIndexed((action: any) => compose(inc3, action))(g)


// => So you can use
// But in this case g2 is any, so I have to define type of g2.
// How can I define type of g2(in this case any) depend on the g
console.log('>>', g2.inc(2), g2.inc2(5)) // 6 and 10
```

In both example the type of g2 is any I would like to define the type of g2 depend on g. 
How can I do that?

Comment: Convert how ? what is the expected result ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir the same type of data, but use keyof

Comment: Well why use `Record<K, number>` then ? Why not just return `T`, Do you wat to just pick certain props ?

Comment: Because I want to handle the result of convertData, in this case is num + 1 | num + 2, but another case is different

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I means I would like convertData is the same `data` including `inc` and `inc2` props but the result will change

Comment: Sorry, still not clear to me, could you provide an expected output that would not be of the  same type as the passed I parameter ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir Thanks for your feedback, I updated my question and 2 examples, If you still not understand feel free to ask. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a mapped type and a conditional type to change the return type of each function in the object:

```
const inc = (n: number) => n + 1
const inc2 = (n: number, count = 2) => n + count
const g = {
    inc,
    inc2,
}
const inc3 = (n: number) => n + 3


type ChnageReturnType<T, R> = {
    [P in keyof T] : T[P] extends (...a: infer A) => any ? (...a: A) => R: never
} 

type AnyReturnType<T> = {
    [P in keyof T] : T[P] extends (a: any) => infer R ? R: never
}[keyof T]

function mapObject<T, R>(o: T, mapFn: (o: AnyReturnType<T>)=> R) :ChnageReturnType<T, R> {
    return Object.keys(g).reduce(
        (previousValue, key) => {
            console.log('pore', previousValue, key)
            return {
                ...previousValue,
                [key]: (...arg: any[]) => { return inc3(g[key](...arg)) },
            }
        },
    {}) as ChnageReturnType<T, R>
}
const g2 = mapObject(g, inc3)
console.log('>>', g2.inc(2), g2.inc2(5)) // both functions fully typed return numbers

const g3 = mapObject(g, o=> o.toString()) // o is types as number but will be typed to a union of all posible return values ()
console.log('>>', g3.inc(2), g3.inc2(5)) // both functions will return strings
```

You can also use just the `ChnageReturnType` type:

```
const g4: ChnageReturnType<typeof g, number> = Object.keys(g).reduce(
    (previousValue, key) => {
        console.log('pore', previousValue, key)
        return {
            ...previousValue,
            [key]: (...arg: any[]) => { return inc3(g[key](...arg)) },
        }
    },
{}) as any
```